# Handle server error python

Tags: python, api, error-handling

I m workin on an api where the user enters a domain and i need to redirect to the login page of that domain.
So this works for only google domains and i need to handle the error created when user enters non google domain . I m workin on google app engine.
I m new to dis error handling.So kindly explain how it works along with the solution

The error i recieved is

//Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.//

thaks in advance

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts, you can now leave comments under answers, edit your question and eventually accept the answer that helped you the most. I'd suggest registering, as you've managed to accidentally create two accounts in the space of 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution will be probably to try to validate the user input before you use it. A simple regular expression which checks the last parts of the domain the user has entered might be enough.

If you want to support arbitrary domains without a `google\.[a-z]+` or `appspot.com` suffix you will need another way to figure out if the site matches your requirements or not. Unfortunately there is no "is-powered-by-google-or-has-a-google-like-login-page" header, so you will probably need to look at the content and use some heuristics if the page is likely to be a such a page or not.

The kind of server error (500 interrnal server error) you are now encountering might mean a lot. This error indicates that there is something wrong with your application or server configuration. For example, if you deploy a script with a syntax error, the web server will response with "server error" when someone tries to access it. Also, if you want to divide by 0 or try to access an non-existing element this kind of error will be shown. So, server-errors are just a very general name for programming errors which should be avoided (and fixed!).

Comment: .. Thankh you very much for your answer, but what i have already kept a check for what have mentioned in your answer. What i need to do is to find out the given domain is google domain , which can be done by goin to the URL . When its a non google domain i m getting an ERROR : SERVER ERROR , how can i catch dis error. what i need to mention in the except <error> . I have tried server error. And is there any method to catch all errors without mentioning them.... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to specify exactly what your case requires, but the way error catching generally works is like this:

```
try:
    something_that_might_fail()
except ErrorClass:
    do_something_else()
```